# How to select multiple checkboxes with the same class but depending on which items have been selected

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows, in this table each row has it's checkbox and a text field (this text field contains class XXX, but is different per row, although sometimes two of more share the same class).

Now I want, when a user selects checkbox 1 (textfield has the class "A") and checkbox 5 (textfield has the class "B") and clicks the button "Select group", to select **all** other checkboxes which have the textfield with class "A" or class "B" in their row.

I was thinking of using `$(this).closest` but I don't know how jQuery really works, so could anyone point me out in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** some html: http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chk1'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value='123' class='A'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chk2'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value='518' class='C'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chk3'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value='321' class='B'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chk4'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value='567' class='A'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='chk5'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' value='971' class='B'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><input type='button' value='Select same classes' onclick='Funcion'>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

So basically, when you select the first checkbox, it should select the 4th aswell. And if you select the 3rd checkbox, it should select the 5th aswell.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want from the information provided.

Comment: This would be easier if you'd add the class to the checkbox, in addition to/instead of the textinput.

Comment: @mblase75 Obviously, yes. Although due to the nature of my form, that isn't quite the working solution for the rest of it in that concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/28/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectAll").click(function(){
        var className, $table = $("table");
        $table.find("input:checked")
        .each(function(){
            className = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text").attr('class');
            $table.find("input[type:text]."+className)
            .closest("tr").find("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My demo is working, I tested in chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: FYI. I have added `id` to select All button in my demo. Make sure you change it accordingly if you using this code as it is.

Comment: IE8. jsFiddle has been misbehaving for me a lot, but not usually this way.

Comment: If jsFiddle is not working then better try my demo in other browser at least to make sure my demo works

Comment: Found it -- IE8 objects to your use of "class" as a variable name. This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/27/

Comment: I see, modified my answer as well as the demo please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/24/

```
$(function() {
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            var c = ($(this).parent().next().children("input:text").attr("class"));
            $("input:text").filter("."+c).parent().prev().children("input:checkbox").prop("checked",true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/25/ uses ShankarSangoli's traversal approach, which is both more compact and more general than my approach above.

Comment: Thank you, yours is also working correctly although I had to change a class of the TR aswell so I found ShankarSangoli's approach easier to understand as a "newb" in jQuery, so I could modify it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":button").click(function(){


$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

var is = $(this).closest("td").next("td").children("input").is(".B,.A");
    if(is)
        $(this).prop("checked",true);

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hg4p6/16/

Comment: You don't know the classnames upfront.